# Disable editing full name user

Tags: username, multiple-users

I have some Ubuntu 14.04 desktops in a school environment with a user account named "Student" for student purposes. Some students replace the username's full name with random stuff, which is possible. Is it possible to block editting the full names as a regular user?

Comment: What about granting them access to a guest-account only and adding write-permissions to a special home-replacement directory?

Answer (score 1):

According to `man chfn`, you should be able to control access to the GECOS data fields using the `CHFN_RESTRICT` setting in `login.defs`

```
CONFIGURATION
       The following configuration variables in /etc/login.defs change the
       behavior of this tool:

       CHFN_RESTRICT (string)
           This parameter specifies which values in the gecos field of the
           /etc/passwd file may be changed by regular users using the chfn
           program. It can be any combination of letters f, r, w, h, for Full
           name, Room number, Work phone, and Home phone, respectively. For
           backward compatibility, yes is equivalent to rwh and no is
           equivalent to frwh. If not specified, only the superuser can make
           any changes. The most restrictive setting is better achieved by not
           installing chfn SUID.
```

Comment: Using CHFN_Restrict works for using the chnf -f command. But you can still change the full name through the user accounts GUI